# How can I link a html button to a codebehind method in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a JQueryTemplate that renders some number of textboxes and corresponding submit buttons. How do I handle the click method of the button? Is there also a way to identify which button was pressed? Each template textbox/button pair has an ID associated with it.

Ideally I would like to simply have a templateButton_click() method and be able to extract the ID and value of the textbox from it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you looking to post back to the server or make an AJAX call or simply execute some client-side script when those submit buttons are clicked?

Answer (score 2):

__doPostBack on the client side is probably what you're after: [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Answer (score 2):

To call a server side method on a client side event you need to do the following:

1- Create the server side method that do whatever you want to do when the client event occured:

```
templateButton_click(string textBoxID)
```

2- Implement the RaisePostBackEvent event handler which take one string argument (That will be the ID of the related TextBox). Call your defined method in it:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(StringeventArgument) : System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent        
{
    templateButton_click(eventArgument)
}
```

3- Write a script to trigger post back action:

```
function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){    
    __doPostBack(control, arg);
}
```

4- Call the PostBack trigger function on the click event of each button and specify the realted TextBox ID as an argument :

```
<button .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('ButtonID', 'RealatedTextBoxID')" .. />
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks pretty cool, thanks for your comprehensive answer, will give it a shot!