# How to call a Javascript function having return value in c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript

I am having a page where i need to **confirm** whether to show updated grid or not

I am calling a javascript function using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "confirm('Are u sure');", true);
```

What I want to know is how to get the return value of confirm in C# code behind.

Comment: You can't get the return value of a client-side JavaScript function directly in server-side C# code-behind, that value would need to be submitted.

Comment: usually with confirms you just cancel the event in the case a user clicked "no". You dont have to submit the form at all in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "confirm('Are u sure');", true);
```

use this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", "ConfirmUser('Are u sure');", true);

<script type='javascript'>
 function ConfirmUser(msg)
 {
  if(confirm(msg))
    __doPostBack('','');
 }
<script>
```

see following links to know more about `__doPostBack`

[1](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Answer (score 3):

> I am having a page where i need to confirm whether to show updated grid or not

You may prevent the postback when use choose `Cancel` button of confirm dialog.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to populate the list?');" 
            Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: But i think vinod want to show confirm box after some manipulation on server side...