# Trigger postback on a particular time in asp.net c# from client side(javascript/jquery)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, timer

I need to do btnRate_Click after particular time on javascript/jquery

```
protected void btnRate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

      {
        if (Session["User"] != null && Session["ActiveDoctor"] != null)
        {                 
            if (objRate.InsertRecord())
                Response.Redirect("../Clinics.aspx", true);
         }
     }
```

Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's a button which has a click event which is tied to btnRate_Click, you can use __doPostback to trigger the post back.

This means you could do something like:

`window.setTimeout(function() { __doPostback('<%= btnRate.UniqueID %>',  '');}, 1000);`

This should 'click' btnRate 1 second after calling the code.

See the following question for more info on __doPostback:

[How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Comment: "Assuming there's a button which has a click event which is tied to btnRate_Click" please explain this.

Comment: You haven't shown us your markup, but it looks like it contains something like `<asp:Button OnClick="btnRate_Click" ID="btnRate" />`. All I meant is that I've assumed this to be true for the purpose of my response.