# Making a mutiline TextBox to trigger button click event on Enter rather going new line

Tags: asp.net, button, textbox, multiline, enter

I want to make an ASP.NET multilined TextBox to trigger the button1_Click() event instead of going newline when ENTER key is pressed. Note that this button is not in a form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with onkeypress and check it if it was enter do button1_performclick().that will do the job for you

Comment: `PerformClick()` method is not found in Web, its for windows, and the question is tagged with asp.net.

Comment: So sorry,So you need to use javascript instead

Answer (score 0):

You will have to track `onkeypress` of TextBox and check it if key pressed was enter or not, If entered was pressed then perform `__dopostback` which will postback your form and on `page_load` check for its arguments. For more information on  `__dopostback` [Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)