# Confirmation message box in webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below message box in asp.net web application. Now i want to convert this message box as a confirmation message box and do something when it is true else means reject the application.

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Are you sure, you want to apply?');</script>", false);
```

Comment: On confirmation what you want to do a client side function or a server side call ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. You should display this confirmation **before** posting back, and then only post back if they choose to "Apply".

Using ASP.NET web controls, the `Button` control has an [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property which can be used to call javascript prior to Http POST:

You could do something like this:

```
<asp:button id="btn"
            runat="server"
            Text="Apply"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to apply?');"
            OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

Comment: It's work for me.. Then how can i use the line break in confirmation message like this "return confirm('Are you sure <br/> you wish to apply?');"

Comment: I believe you use `\n` instead of `<br />`

Comment: I use like this 'Are you +'\n'+ you wish to apply?' it's not working

Comment: Just use `Are you \n you wish to apply?`. No string breaks required

Answer (score 3):

register script bellow instead of alert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var r=confirm("Are you sure you are sure?")
if (r==true)
{
  //You pressed OK!
}
else
{
  //You pressed Cancel!
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript equivalent to a confirmation box is the confirm() method. This method returns a true or false value depending on the user's "OK" or "Cancel" button response.

**Usage:**

```
var confirmed = confirm('Are you sure?','Are you sure you want to delete this item?');

if(confirmed){
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add this on your cs file to display a `confirm` instead of `alert`

```
string confirm = 
"if(confirm('Are you surely want to do this ??')) __doPostBack('', 'confirmed');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", confirm, true);
```

Add this on same page to check when user is coming from that confirmation box

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (string.Equals("confirmed", 
                        parameter, 
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Call your server side method here
    }
}
```

For this I used `__doPostBack` you can learn more about it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback).
Hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

try this code check on `OnClientClick` event when user click on button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function check()
     {          
        var chk =confirm("Are you sure you are sure?")
        if (chk==true)
        {
            // try you want
        }
        else
        {
            // try you do not want
        }
       return true;
     }

</script>        

 <asp:button id="Button1"
        runat="server"
        Text="Button1"
        OnClientClick="return check();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showMessage(string msg){

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('"+ msg +"');</script>", false);
```

protected void BtnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        OracleHelper.OracleDBOpen();
        object flag = OracleHelper.OracleExecuteScalar("your select Query ");
        if (flag == null)
        {
                      showMessage("Failed !!! ");

        }
        else
        {
            string reg = String.Format("your Insert Query ");

            showMessage("successfuly");
            OracleHelper.OracleExecuteNonQuery(reg);

        }                
        OracleHelper.OracleDBClose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this completely within C#, you can try this:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {  
        AddConfirmationButton();   
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void AddConfirmationButton()
    {   
        Button confirmButton = new Button();
        confirmButton.Text = "Action Foo";
        string confirmationMessage = "Are you sure you wish to do action Foo?";
        confirmButton.OnClientClick = "return confirm('" + confirmationMessage + "');";
        confirmButton.Command += confirmButton_Command;

        Controls.Add(confirmButton);

    }

    void confirmationMessage_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DoActionFoo();   //work your magic here.
    }
```

This presents and "OK/Cancel" dialog box to the user from the webpage.  If the user clicks 'ok', the function from the command Event fires.  If the user clicks 'cancel',  nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page,this.GetType(), "temp","javascript:calopen();
",true);

function calopen()    
{    
    if (confirm("Are you sure?"+'\n'+"Are you want to delete"))    
    {   
        enter code here    
    }
    else   
    {   
        return false;
    }    
}
```