# Use JS & ASP in 1 HTML onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, events, asp-classic, onclick

How can I call an ASP function and a Javascript function from one HTML Button OnClick event?
-- Not using ASP.NET

```
onclick="SetDiv('titel', 'trSchrijver', 'boek')"
```

JS

Combined with

```
onclick="<% boek.GetSchrijver %>"
```

ASP

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will have to make an AJAX call to call the ASP-function since it recides on the server and the javascript is on the client...

Comment: @ianpgall: that's Dutch for `book.GetAuthor`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look into this framework for Classic ASP with easy AJAX support:
http://ajaxed.org/

Answer (score -1):

The ASP Button control has a `OnClientClick` and a `OnClick` attribute. The first is used to define a JavaScript string to be executed client-side, the second is used to define an event handler method (an ASP function) to be executed server-side after a postback. You can use both.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
   text="Execute ASP and JS"
   onClientClick="alert('I am JavaScript!')"
   runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

In your codebehind file:

```
void Button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Do C# stuff ...
}
```

Documentation:
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

---

If you do not want to use the ASP Button control, you can instead use the JS function __doPostBack() in a normal HTML element.

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave"
  onclick="doSomething(); __doPostBack('btnSave ', 'parameter');"
  value="click me"/>
```

In your codebehind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
  // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // btnSave
}
```

See [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback) where I got the example from.