# Executing Server-Side Methods by Clicking on a DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm working on an **ASP.Net** project, with **C#**.

Usually, when I need to put **Buttons** that will **execute some methods**, I will use the ASP Controller (Button) inside a **runat="server"** form.

But I feel that this really limits the capabilities of my website, because when I used to work with **JSP**, I used **jquery** to reach a **servlet** to execute some codes and return a **responseText**.

I did not check yet how this is done in ASP.Net, but my question concerns controllers and the famous **runat="server"**.

When I add a **runat="server"** to any **HTML Element**, I'm supposed to be able to manipulate this HTML element in C# (Server-Side), and this actually works, I can change the **ID**, set the **InnerText** or **InnerHtml**, but the thing that I can't get, is **why can't I execute a method by clicking on this element?**

The "**onclick**" attribute is for JavaScript I think, and **OnServerClick** doesn't seem to work as well. Is it something wrong with my codes? or this doesn't work at all?

Comment: could you show us your codes?

Comment: You may want to use ASP.NET MVC then...

Comment: @mdcuesta it's not about codes, it's about a concept, but here you go : <div id="blabla" runat="server" OnClick="Test">Hello</div>

Comment: @Lucero I'm forced to use Web Forms.

Comment: divs with runat attributes doesn't have a serverclick event, you need to handle it using ajax/jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to execute server side methods by clicking on a div or anything on your page. The first is mentioned __dopostback, second is handling the click in javascript or with jQuery and calling a function in a handler or a page method in a webservice or a page method in your page behind code. 
Here is the handler version:

```
 $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/Handler1.ashx?param1=someparam',
            success: function(msg, status, xhr) {
                //doSomething, manipulate your html
            },
            error: function() {  
             //doSomething
            }
        });
 });
```

I think the second version is better, because you can make a partial postback without any updatepanel, asyncronously. The drawback is, the server side code is separated from your page behind code.

Handler:

```
public class Handler1: IHttpHandler
{
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
      context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
      var param1= context.Request.QueryString["param1"];
      //param1 value will be "someparam"

      // do something cool like filling a datatable serialize it with newtonsoft jsonconvert

      var dt= new DataTable();
      // fill it
      context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt));
   }
}
```

If everything is cool, you get the response in the ajax call in the success section, and the parameter called "msg" will be your serialized JSON datatable.

Comment: I'm glad that you liked it :)

Comment: @spetie43, could you update your answer with a small example about how the Handler could look like? Just to know how to use the returned parameters (msg, status, xhr)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to handle the click in the `div` using the `Jquery`  and call
server-side methods through `JQuery`

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a method from jquery click in server, using __doPostBack javascript function, see this threat for more details [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your jquery on div onclick and pass DIv id whcih call click

```
__doPostBack('__Page', DivID);
```

On page load add this code

```
if (IsPostBack)
            {
    //you will get id of div which called function
    string eventargs = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventargs))
                    {
                       //call your function 
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the div runat="server" and id="divName"

in page_Load event in cs:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "divClick")
{
    //code to run in click event of divName
}
}

divName.Attributes.Add("ondivClick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(divName, "divClick"));
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

if you are referring to divs with runat="server" attributes, they don't have onserverclick events, that's why it doesn't work