# How do I create an ordinary HTML button that posts back?

Tags: asp.net

I need a button different than the normal server side one because I may need to hide or disable it.

Comment: It is not possible to understand what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Just by examining key words in your question and inferring what you might be asking, this question might be relevant: [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

If you don't want to render an

```
<asp:Button/>
```

control or if you don't have one available, you can call the `__doPostBack()` method in javascript (provided at least one control on the page has rendered this method)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want a html button to submit your form? something like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

if so input type="submit" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not really clear what you really want, the following might help you:

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.reload();" ONMOUSEOVER="window.status='Refresh'; return true" ONMOUSEOUT="window.status='Page Reloading'"> RELOAD </a>
```

OR

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(0)">Refresh the Page</a>
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```