# Update an UpdatePanel when ModalDialog closes or on button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, modal-dialog

I have two pages.  The first one has one button and an UpdatePanel that contains an image.
The button uses the following code to show a ModalDialog:

```
window.showModalDialog('AjustarImagem.aspx', 
                                        null,
                                       'status:no;
                                        LOCATION: NO;
                                        TOOLBAR=NO ;
                                        DIRECTORIES: NO; 
                                        dialogWidth:250px;
                                        dialogHeight:300px;
                                        dialogHide:true;
                                        help:no;
                                        scroll:yes');  
                                        return false;");
```

What I need to do is to update the UpdatePanel when the ModalDialog closes, or when the click event of the ModalDialog button fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the __doPostBack() at the onclick javascript event of your button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function ReloadPanel() {
            //debugger;
            // Realiza un postback parcial al panel de ajax.
            __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', parametro);
        }
    </script>
```

And add the load event of the update panel for process the request if you want:

protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the parameter
        string arg = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) return;    

}
```

View this post: [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Hope this helps.