# enable postback onclick of a hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hyperlink as

```
<a href="" id="link1">Click</a>
```

I have do enable a post back action whenever this link is clicked.

We can do

`<a href="" id="link1" onclick="javascript:location.reload()">Click</a>`

However, I want to do a page postback and not a page reload.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinkButton` instead?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, `<a>` elements should be links for GET resources, not for POST form submission.

Answer (score 8):

Simple, use a [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) instead.

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Label1.Text="This is a postback";
}
```

on aspx:

```
  <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
       Text="Click Me" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

You are using a html link, if you want to use serverside code i would suggest to use server controls. However, if you reallly insist you could call [__doPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback) manually via javascript.

```
<a id="linkId"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="__doPostBack('linkId', '');">click me</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do it using the hyperlink. The existing system already has a hyperlink and I don't want to change that to a Link Button

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='void()' onclick="javascript:postBackFromLink('<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>'); return false;">Refresh Me</a><br />
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1077801.aspx?client+__doPostBack+from+within+a+usercontrol+Problem+Click+event+in+code+behind+never+reached+

bu it just usefull for usercontrol based dopostbacks