# Prevent this postback

Tags: javascript, html, postback, href

I want to be able to prevent this postback without actually editing the HTML itself.

```
<a class="button campaign-button" id="ctl00_main_fastcheckout_FastCart_FastDiscount_lbDiscountCode" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$main$fastcheckout$FastCart$FastDiscount$lbDiscountCode','')"><span>OK</span></a>
```

Is there a default way of disabling postbacks perhaps on document load?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why use a link button if you don't want it to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `return false`.

```
OnClientClick="yourFunction(); return false;"
```

In `js`:

```
yourFunction(){
    //code
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: He can always return false in JS function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Java script on your page

```
window.__doPostBack = function(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
return false;
};
```

But this is not the recommended way.

check out this[how-does-the-dopostback-method-get-called-where-is-the-calling-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678481/how-does-the-dopostback-method-get-called-where-is-the-calling-method)