# Calling C# function through Javascript (without Json)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a function named "callfunction()" in JavaScript(Mypage.aspx) .This function should call  another function "func()" in C# (Mypage.aspx.cs )

Something like this:

(in Mypage.aspx)

```
 function callfunction()

 {

  // i have to call func() function here .....

 }

 </script>
```

(in Mypage.aspx.cs file)

```
 public void func()

 {

 // My code goes here

 }
```

I have researched alot because of this and i ended up so far with 2 conclusions:
1st was to use Json, but my superiors said clearly that they dont want me to do so.
2nd was that i cant do as i wish because of the client, server aspnet protocol

Please give me any kind of tip in how to do this, i am getting desperate

Comment: You should use Ajax on it.. It is very easy to implement..

Comment: no need for json you can call an event handler of any hidden button of aspx using _postback()

Comment: Hum maybe using postback would be a solution from now, but i dont know if i need more specific way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a webforms project (not MVC) and you don't want to use AJAX, you can use [__doPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function callfunction(parameter)
 {
     __doPostBack('func', parameter)
 }
</script>
```

C#:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
  var senderObject = Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // func
  if(senderObject == "func")
  {
     //call your function here, or write the implementation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok....Try using [`page methods`](http://codehandbook.org/an-asp-net-way-to-call-server-side-methods-using-javascript/)

First add a script manager on your aspx page

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then go to your aspx.cs page and declare a function something like

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ValidateUser(string emailId, string password)
    {
        //Your logic code
        return returnString;
    }
```

Then from your javascript call the c# method like

```
 PageMethods.ValidateUser(email, password, CallSuccess_Login, CallFailed_Login);
```

And also in ur javascript create 2 call back functions `CallSuccess_Login` and `CallFailed_Login`

Hope it helps

Comment: This seems to me to be the "use json" answer.  I believe they don't want him to use a web service.

Comment: doesn't have to be json.It can be a return type of string too. :)

Comment: i am not sure but don't think it has to be JSON in the return type

Comment: ill talk with my superiors to ask if i can use page methods, anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

below are the options available to you

1. If your using asp.net then use Ajax tools to create this
2. if you don’t want to user Ajax toolkit use JavaScript __doPostBack
3. or other option write server side function in the web service and call web method using JavaScript