# JQuery ajax return list from c# function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

I'm a bit confused when trying to implement C# and jquery to work together. I have a .cs file and a javascript document in the same solution/project. My c# function returns a list of strings, which I would like to append to some HTML data using Javascript. I am also using a webform for my HTML. Is it possible to return my list on the javascript side?

javascript

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Test/GetListData", 
        dataType: "data: Array<any>" //Something like this?
    });

    //Can i return the list and use it here?
});
```

c# method

```
public List<string> GetListData()
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    mylist.Add("test1");
    mylist.Add("test2");
    mylist.Add("test3");
    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: the jQuery `$.ajax` docs are very well detailed and even include examples

Comment: What kind of web-application is it? webforms or mvc?

Comment: @VenkataPanga Web forms

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402242/calling-c-sharp-function-through-javascript-without-json/17402494#17402494  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264373/jquery-ajax-call-to-asp-net-webforms-returns-html-page-instead-of-calling-the-sp

Comment: @VenkataPanga Thanks for the advice. It turns out I had to go in an entirely different direction, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after careful research I realized that I was going about my problem the wrong way. I wanted to have C# communicate with javascript/html for a web form in the same project. Using a list was a bad idea as my javascript couldnt effectively see it unless I formatted it as one big JSON String. Here is the updated code that solved my problem, hopefully it helps someone down the line. [ComVisible(true)] allows the external window named test to see my c# function, and the $.parseJSON(myarray) was able to parse my JSON string into a usable array.

c#

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public string GetData()
{
    string test = "[{"Name": "test1"}, {"Name": test2"}, {"Name": "test3"}]";
    return test;
}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var test = window.external;
            var myarray = test.GetData();
            var obj = $.parseJSON(myarray);
            alert(obj[1].Name);
        }

   </script>
```

Comment: Did you mean: `{"Name": "test2"},` 
instead of `{"Name": test2"}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Pulled from [this thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json)

You can serialize that list into some nice tidy JSON like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(aList);
```

Comment: So is it necessary to serialize my list to JSON in order to use the data in JQuery?

Comment: It'd be the easiest way to go about it. JSON objects are light and easily parsed by jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. See my updated answer below for how I solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Note: I had a file already setup so the name is different):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetListData",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });

        });

        function OnSuccess(data)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < data.all.length; i++)
            {
                alert(data.all[i].textContent);
            }
        }
        function OnError(data)
        {
            alert(data.statusText);
        }
    </script>
```