# ListBox fire onclick Event

Tags: listbox

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  
                             AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged ="button_click"
                >

                <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem >Item 2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
```

I have this code in .aspx file
But I need to fire onclick Event ,not when I only change an item from Item 1 to Item 2. so what should i do? There is no onclick event.

Comment: A listbox doesn't contain a OnClick-event.

Comment: I got it really so is there a solution?

Comment: Add the event via javascript and make a postback with `__doPostBack('<%=ListBox1.ClientID%>', 'click');` Then you could catch it in codebehind by reading this link [How to use __doPostBack()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Comment: Thanks everything works fine))))))