# get specific attribute from html input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can get value from html input by:
Request["inputID"]

But, How to get **data-myatt** attribute from input below in server-side:

```
<input id="input1" type="text" value="value" data-myatt="my date" />
```

Comment: Show us your code my friend.

Comment: this is my input: <input type="text"
    id="costCenterInput"
    data-isComboBox="true"
    data-datasourceName="costCenters" />

Comment: You need to update your question, show us your C# code, in full if possible and your html in full if possible.

Comment: thank you Mr Gray: in server side I can get value by "String s = Request["costCenterInput"]", but how to get "data-datasourceName"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.net web forms then all you have to do is to add the attribute `runat="server"` to the input tag, then you will have access to it and it's attributes.

If you changed the attribute on the client side and you want to have access to it on the server side, you'll have to put that data in another hidden input and get your value from there...

Comment: thank you _Jamshid Asadzadeh_<br/>your answer is my case:<br/> i change the att in client side and i need to get the new value on server side<br/>runat="server" shows predefined attributes but not ay attributes<br/>can i get my att without hidden input?

Comment: As far as I know, No you can't! This is because http post method will send only field values. You can always set the hidden input's value before postback by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can get input value by the following method,

```
 var input_value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
```

To get the specific attribute value you need,

```
var attribute_value = document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('data-myatt');
```

or if you are using Jquery you can simply get attribute value by using,

```
$('#input1').attr('data-myatt);
```

Comment: Thank you securedeveloper, but my case is server-sice "c#" not client-side

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a hidden html input for your request to pass back to your code behind:

```
<input type="text" name="costCenterInput" data-isComboBox="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="costCenters" />
```

in your c#:

```
String costCenterInput = Request["costCenterInput"];
String costCenters = Request["costCenters"];
```

Or you can do some postback nastiness, see my answer here:

[How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback/3914500#3914500)

Comment: Thank You Mr Gray, It seems that this is only way, thank you for __doPostBack() again. ^_^