# Making postback using __doPostBack in asp for filtering grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am in the process of adding a filter to asp grid. I have succeeded in showing a text box for filtering in header.
I need to fire server code for filtering whenever user presses enter key in textbox.
So I started with adding event like

```
txtFilter.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", keyUpScript);
```

Then I added client script as

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "registerkeyUPScript", registerkeyUPScript, true);
```

where

```
string keyUpScript = "keyUPScript(event);";

string registerkeyUPScript = "function keyUPScript(e){\n" 
                                        + "var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;\n" 
                                        + "if(unicode == '13')\n" 
                                            +"{\n"
                                                +" //PostBack code"
                                            +"}"
                                        +"}";
```

Now how could I postback when ever user enters a string in text box and presses enter key. I also need to rebind the filtered data back to grid

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [How to use __doPostBack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this line of code to attach an `onkeyup` to your `TextBox` to only fire a postback event when `Enter` is pressed. Also, just in case you want to attach an `OnTextChanged` event for that particular TextBox, you can do so and that will be called as well when the page postbacks.

Use this in your `Page_Load` event :

```
TextBoxID.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return (event.keyCode==13);");
```

And this is the `OnTextChanged` event just in case if you want to attach :

```
protected void T1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your logic goes here
}
```

Hope this helps.