# JavaScript popup not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel

I'm working on excel sheet where I'm writing data to the excel sheet after data being entered in the excel I'm downloading it to the local disk.

Then I want to show the popup that it has been downloaded successfully and written this code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
lblLog.Text = "Successfully Downloaded";
```

My `JavaScript` is

```
function openModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

My clickevent

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClick="linkbutton_Click" Text="Submit"  data-target="#myModal"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The excel is being downloaded but the popup is not showing

Comment: It seems there is not "modal" method in jQuery, have you tried : `$('#myModal').show();` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick way to show model and trigger your Linkbutton Event

1. Clear your LinkButton OnClick Event and Add OnClientClick="openModal()"

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClientClick="openModal()" Text="Submit"  data-target="#myModal"></asp:LinkButton>
   ```
2. Add trigget Linkbutton Event on your Javascript method

   ```
   function openModal() {

   $('#myModal').modal('show'); // If that is right method

   __doPostBack('linkbutton_Click', ''); //Trigger Linkbutton Event

   }
   ```

   ref:[How to use dopostback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)