# Creating form tag programmatically not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a simple web page that contains a Literal, now I want to create a form tag in code behind.
This is an example:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    Literal1.Text = "form submit";
}
else
{
    Literal1.Text = "<form id='myFrom' runat='server' action='default.aspx'
                     method='POST'><input type='submit' value='click here'/></form>";
}
```

This code create the form, but when I click the submit button, it doesn't go through IsPostBack path. **Why?**

Note that I need it to be created and sent as an string, because I want to use it in ajax for example.

Comment: Are you using web forms or MVC?

Comment: What happens when you remove action attribute from form ?

Comment: Yes I'm using webform. and no difference when removing action attrib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my code to this:

```
if (Context.Request.Form.HasKeys()) // instead of if(IsPostBack)
{
    Literal1.Text = "isPostBack";
}
else
{
    Literal1.Text = "<form id='myFrom' runat='server' action='default.aspx' method='POST'><input type='submit' name='submitbtn' value='click here'/></form>";
}
```

Using different examples, I didn't find any exception to this. and it works well.

Any idea about this solution?

Note that in this way at least one of our elements in the form should have the name property.

Answer (score 0):

IsPostBack is only enabled when the POST request originates from ASP.NET's __doPostBack() function. See [How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback) for how to create an async postback request with JavaScript.

Comment: For some reasons I dont want to use javascript. Note that when I click the submit button the page refresh and form submission occurs. is there any other way to understand that (rather than postback)?

Comment: You could put a hidden value into the form and check for its existence.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get the idea. Would you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET web form is already an HTML form and encompasses all of your controls.  You are nesting a form within a form which is not legal HTML.

I'd suggest you replace your nested form with a simple button.  In the click handler for the button, redirect to default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by John Wu, you don't want to implement your code this way. Nested forms -- while browsers forgive them -- are just not the way to go, especially with ASP.Net WebForms. Sure, I was able to get your code to work, BUT if you need to ajaxify your page so that it works with the WebForms postback model, then it would be much better to use the UpdatePanel control (in conjunction with the ScriptManager control).

ASP.Net WebForms is predicated on only having a single Form element used on a page, as it relates to its postback model, so you'll want to work within that constraint.

Here's some code to demonstrate the use of the UpdatePanel to ajaxify a WebForm (and take advantage of PostBack):

...the .ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NestedForm_Question.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowAspNetQuestionAnswers.NestedForm_Question" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

...the associated code-behind class:

```
   public partial class NestedForm_Question : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SubmitButton.Click += SubmitButton_Click;
        }

        void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal1.Text = "form submit";
        }
    }
```

You can see that in the code-behind class, the code that would need to be written to set the value of the literal control after the Button is clicked is the same whether the page is ajaxified or not.