# How to make onserverclick hit for html button in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Yes I've read a lot on how to make this thing work, but unfortunately mine is a dynamic button and all **id** are unique; so it's created using `StringBuilder` in C# like so:

```
html.Append("<button id=\"" + dr["ID"].ToString() + "\" type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"btnShowModal_ServerClick\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i></button>");
```

Obviously it opens up a modal, but I want to do something before it opens up the modal inside the `btnShowModal_ServerClick` event. Sadly it doesn't hit, the event, but it hits the `Page_Load` event because of the attribute `type="submit"` which makes the modal NOT show up.  Any workaround on this? i've been spending 3hrs on this already.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for. To trigger postback from the HTML button http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914500/2952405

Comment: nope, my button is dynamically created and id is unique that one only have same id

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirement, this is how you can implement

Create your dynamic HTML controls with OnClick event pointing to a javascript method `btnShowModal_ServerClick`

```
html.Append("<button id=\"" + dr["ID"].ToString() + "\" type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" runat=\"server\" onclick=\"javascript:btnShowModal_ServerClick('" + dr["ID"] + "')\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i></button>");
```

Then in `btnShowModal_ServerClick` javaScript function, trigger your modal popup to show up. An important thing to note in my below JavaScript function, is how I assign a callback function to an imaginary popup. This callback will be invoked when you click OK in popup modal.

**NOTE :** *Most modal plugins will have a way to specify the callback funtions on `Yes` or `No` selection*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function btnShowModal_ServerClick(parameterId)
{
      showModal({
          callBackFn : function(){ 
               __doPostBack('btnSave', parameterId);
          }
      });
 }
</script>
```

When you select **yes**, callBack function attached to the modal popup will execute and it will trigger a .NET postback specified within that.

So when the page postback & reloads you can test the Event argument to get back the value specified by dr["ID""] like below

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
  if(Request["__EVENTTARGET"] =="btnSave")
   { /*Do Something with the parameter = dr["ID"]*/}
}
```

Comment: so i have 10buttons i will have 10 if-else statement?

Comment: It is not about if else statements. That was provided for example. You can use the parameter value to do a database query