# Using Bootbox prompt in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, webforms, bootbox

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the Bootbox's prompt functionality in my ASP.NET webforms.Currently I'm using the default JS prompt as follows:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    function defaultval() {
        var pmt = prompt('Please enter a name for the template.',
            document.getElementById('HiddenFieldCurrentTemplate').value);
        return pmt;
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveTemplate" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary"  OnClientClick="HiddenField1.value = defaultval()" Text="Save as Template" />
```

Basically I need help in replacing the default JS prompt with Bootbox's prompt and assign the value returned by the prompt to a hidden field like I currently doing with **OnClientClick="HiddenField1.value = defaultval()"**

Comment: Try bootbox.confirm
<script>
function defaultval(){
bootbox.prompt('Please enter a name for the template.', function(result){ console.log(result); });
}
http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

Comment: The dialog just pops up and postback happens no matter what :-(

Comment: Can u please share your code?

Comment: <script>
  function defaultval() {
            bootbox.prompt(
                'Please enter a name for the template.',
                function (result) { return result; });
        }
</script> 

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="HiddenField1.value = defaultval()" Text="Button2" />

Comment: As we note in the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-prompt-dialog), you can't use bootbox.prompt as a drop-in replacement for the native prompt. I would need some time to create an answer, but basically, you need to prevent postback, call the prompt function, and then manually trigger postback ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)) if the result fits your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet.

Use asp.net web controls instead of html control i used below

```js
function defaultval() {
 bootbox.prompt("This is the default prompt!", function(result){ $("#HiddenField1").val(result);
$('#form1').submit();
 });
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
<input type='submit' onclick='return defaultval()' id='btnSubmit' name='btnSubmit' value="Save as Template" />

<input type='hidden' id='HiddenField1' name='HiddenField1' />
</form1>
```

**[Edit]**

Please find the ASP.NET version

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick='return defaultval()' Text="Save as Template" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
</form>
    <script>
        function defaultval() {
            event.preventDefault();
            bootbox.prompt("This is the default prompt!", function (result) {
                if (result != null && result!='') {
                    $("#HiddenField1").val(result);
                    $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").click();
                } else {
                    alert('please enter something in textbox');
                    return false;
                }
            });
           
        }
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code

```html
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(HiddenField1.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The value does get assigned to the hidden field as the alert displays it but unfortunately postback isnt occurring when I use asp.net button control

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return defaultval()"/>

Comment: Earlier you said, you dont want postback . I think you want to use the assigned hidden value in the code behind. , right? I edited the code.

Comment: Nope. Not working. I do want a postback once I have had a chance to enter a value in the prompt and that value is saved to the hidden field as I wasn't to deal with the value in hidden field at server-side...sorry I want clear about that. Also I think the forced form submission works on html forms and not webforms if I remember correctly.

Comment: webforms are rendered as HTML forms. Forced submitssion work on webforms as well. Further to add this, you can check call back feature of bootbox

Comment: Copied and pasted your code as is. Nothing happens now when button is clicked.Just a postback occurs. Browser console in Firefox shows the following error:

ReferenceError: event is not defined[Learn More]         WebForm2:29:9
defaultval   http://localhost:4359/WebForm2:29:9
onclick      http://localhost:4359/WebForm2:1:8